# Error 403 You are not authorized to perform this action in yii framework

Tags: yii

I have followed http://www.larryullman.com/2010/01/04/simple-authentication-with-the-yii-framework/ for creating login system using database.
but after login and trying to access admin pages i got

```
Error 403 You are not authorized to perform this action
```

any idea why how to solve this issue?
see my access rule

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
    array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
        'actions'=>array('index','view'),
        'users'=>array(''),
    ),
    array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
        'actions'=>array(),
        'users'=>array('@'),
    ),
    array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
        'actions'=>array('admin','delete','create','update' ),  // 
        'users'=>array('admin'),
        'expression'=>'isset($user->role) && ($user->role==="admin")',
    ),
    array('deny',  // deny all users
        'users'=>array(''),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: you need to add permission(user permissions) in your model. Check Yii guide too.

Comment: I have default permission that comes with Model, do i need to change that?

Comment: Can you check what is there for the admin pages that you are accessing. You might need to add the accessRules for the type of user you are creating. Please see my answer also. Also posting(append at the bottom of your question) what you have will greatly help.

Comment: The following is what i am talking about : array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view', 'youradmintask'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        )

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Make sure that your accessRules() has allowed admin action to & (signed in), and IT IS ON TOP OF ALL OTHER RULES OR AT LEAST JUST PUT IT ON TOP OF THE DENY ALL RULE. Don't get me wrong, it is not required to be always on top of all other rules, but the default last rule in the book is to deny *, so if you put your admin rule below it, you won't have a chance to access action admin.

```
 public function accessRules()
        {
                return array(
                         array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                        'actions'=>array('index','view', 'checkout'),
                        'users'=>array('*'),
                    )
                );
        }
```

**2-** If you have correctly updated your accessRules(), you need to check to make sure your account you're using to sign in, is the user who has access to the admin pages. This operation is obviously in task user management, and assigned to role owner. So the user must be the owner of the project you're currently browse. Go selecting from your database to make sure on that.